# How can one reason this conditional probability?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I'm very stuck in a problem that includes the following relationship:

$P(Y \in G|a=0) = P(Y \in G|a=1) \cdot \frac{\frac{P(a=0|Y \in G)}{P(a=1|Y \in G)}}{\frac{P(a=0)}{P(a=1)}}$

here $a$ denotes a variable that can only take values 0 and 1 and $G$ is an arbitrary measurable set. How can one derive this formula? How is this reasoned properly? I'm very confused. This is done in order to compute a conditional distribution where $a=0$ is given.

Comment: Just do the algebra.  $P(Y\in G|x,a=1)P(a=0|x)=$$P(Y\in G|x,a=1)P(a=1|x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Every probability here is conditioned on $x$, so for simplicity we can drop $x$ from everywhere (all the computations will be valid and proceed in the same way if they are all conditioned on $x$). So, you have

\begin{eqnarray*}
P\left(a=0\,|\,Y\in G\right) &=& \frac{P\left(Y\in G, a=0\right)}{P\left(Y\in G\right)},\\
P\left(a=1\,|\,Y\in G\right) &=& \frac{P\left(Y\in G, a=1\right)}{P\left(Y\in G\right)}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Dividing the first line by the second yields

$$\frac{P\left(a=0\,|\,Y\in G\right)}{P\left(a=1\,|\,Y\in G\right)} = \frac{P\left(Y\in G, a=0\right)}{P\left(Y\in G, a=1\right)}$$

Multiplying this quantity by $P\left(Y\in G\,|\,a=1\right)$ yields $\frac{P\left(Y\in G, a=0\right)}{P\left(a=1\right)}$. Dividing by $\frac{P\left(a=0\right)}{P\left(a=1\right)}$  replaces the denominator by $P\left(a=0\right)$, which gives you $P\left(Y\in G\,|\,a=0\right)$, as required.